# How to reduce or disable shared RAM on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, vram

I have a dedicated GPU with 8GB and 32GB of RAM but 16GB of RAM is being shared with the CPU; so de OS only can access 16GB.

In the B450-F Asus BIOS doesn't show any way to change this.

I don't know if this is being do it by the BIOS, the Nvidia drivers or by Windows itself.

Please help.

[image: RAM CPU-Z]
[image: Task Manager GPU]

Comment: hm, why do you think GPU part is relevant? Other than that, this might be a relevant discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/bu171x/windows_10_32gb_ram_all_available_but_only_16gb/

Comment: Can you run [cpu-z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and show us a screenshot of the "Memory" tab?

Comment: @Mokubai Done it

Comment: @E_Blue You see the "Memoria" tab showing how much is available to Windows? It's saying that 4.5 out of *31.9* GB is in use.

Comment: Your task manager shot is showing 0.0GB of 16GB "shared", it should not be using your RAM at all. The next thing to try is allocating a whole bunch of RAM using the Microsoft `testlimit` program https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/testlimit `Testlimit64.exe -d 17000 -c 1` should allocate about 17GB of RAM. and you can see in task manager or use [perfmon](https://serverfault.com/a/694676) to see if page file usage goes up which would indicate that 16GB is unable to be used for some reason. On my system `testlimit` quickly allocates RAM and I see no pagefile change at all.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, I saw that. That amount of used RAM is only OS and the Web Browser; when I start the VMs and some IDE never saw it to go over 16GB; that's why I was worried. Now I opened a lot of heavy programs and the OS used RAM goes to 24GB. So it seems that It's working fine; I just was worried that that shared RAM was reserved only for the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Memory shared with the GPU is not blocked off to the operating system. The GPU is not your problem.

My system is 32GB RAM, and the GPU shows 16GB shared memory, but all 32GB is still usable by the operating system *unless* it is actually in use by the graphics card and that will only happen if you've used all the GPU RAM first.

I've seen in the past some systems will detect a stick of RAM but not be able to use it. In general the problems are

1. The CPU does not support that much RAM to begin with. Unlikely with a B450 motherboard which as far as I can see should support 64GB
2. The RAM is mismatched. Potentially RAM with different clocks or timings may not work well together.
3. The RAM is not in the correct slots. You should make sure that the RAM is in the correct slots by consulting your motherboard manual. Typically RAM should be populated in the slots A2 & B2 before other slots.
4. The RAM is not correctly seated. I have seen before that *sometimes* an incorrectly seated stick of RAM might be detected enough to show the SPD timings (which comes off a chip on one of the slower lines going to the module) but not being fully connected means the module shows as "hardware reserved".

Comment: I use virtual machines(4GB each) and some IDEs like Android Studio(10GB) that uses a lot of RAM and the system never goes over 16GB used, so is using the C: disk.